# Different style depending on device's width and height

Tags: css, media-queries, device-width

I have to define different textarea heights, depending on the device:

- if the user is using an iPhone **4**, the textarea's height must be `62px`,
- if the user is using an iPhone **5**, the textarea's height must be `106px`.

This is my current CSS. It works for the iPhone **5**, but if I load the page on an iPhone **4**, it uses the style defined for the iPhone **5**.

```
/* iPhone 2G-4S in portrait */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
    textarea {
        height: 62px;
    }
}

/* iPhone 5 & 5S in portrait */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 568px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
    textarea {
        height: 106px;
    }
}
```

Why isn't the page loaded in an iPhone **4** using the `62px` value?